# How to generate file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

For instance, I have such JSON:

```
{
  "extends": "core-range",
  "dependencies": [
    "paper-progress",
    "paper-input"
  ],
  "jsdoc": [
    {
      "description": "Fired when the slider's value changes.",
      "kind": "event",
      "name": "core-change",
      "longname": "event:core-change"
    },
    {
      "name": "snaps",
      "kind": "member",
      "longname": "snaps",
      "scope": "global"
    },
    {
      "name": "pin",
      "kind": "member",
      "longname": "pin",
      "scope": "global"
    },
    {
      "name": "disabled",
      "kind": "member",
      "longname": "disabled",
      "scope": "global"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to generate such Java class:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.js.JsProperty;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.js.JsType;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener;

@JsType(prototype = "HTMLElement", isNative = true)
public interface PaperSlider extends HTMLElement , CoreRange {
  Class<?>[] dependencies = new Class<?>[]{PaperProgress.class, PaperInput.class};

  void addEventListener(String event, EventListener listener);

  @JsProperty PaperSlider snaps(boolean val);
  @JsProperty boolean snaps();

  @JsProperty PaperSlider pin(boolean val);
  @JsProperty boolean pin();

  @JsProperty PaperSlider disabled(boolean val);
  @JsProperty boolean disabled();
}
```

What's the best way to generate it? Probably it makes sense to use templates. The most difficult part is methods generation.

I didn't find any Node.js module which supports repetable templates.

BTW, I have many JSON files and I'm going to add this to my Gulp task for generation some source files.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a few mutually recursive functions to do that? Basically a kind of recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to go about this. I would recommend doing it via [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Install grunt globally:

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Then install your local grunt (in your current directory):

```
npm install grunt
```

Create the template (class.tmpl):

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.js.JsProperty;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.js.JsType;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener;

@JsType(prototype = "HTMLElement", isNative = true)
public interface PaperSlider extends HTMLElement , CoreRange {
  Class<<%= className %>>[] dependencies = new Class<<%= className %>>[]{PaperProgress.class, PaperInput.class};

  void addEventListener(String event, EventListener listener);

  <% _.forEach(methods,function(method){ %>
       <%= method.description && ("// " + method.description) %>
      @JsProperty PaperSlider <%= method.name %>(boolean val);
      @JsProperty boolean <%= method.name %>();
  <% }) %>

}
```

And finally create the `Gruntfile.js`:

```
// config is your JSON file
// Yes, you can require json files
var config = require("./config");

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask("makeClass",function() {
        var template = grunt.file.read("./class.tmpl");
        var fileData = grunt.template.process(template,{
            data: {
                methods: config.jsdoc,
                className: "JSClass"
            }
        });
        grunt.file.write("./class.java", fileData);
    })

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["makeClass"]);
};
```

Now simply run `grunt`.

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. I already use gulp in my project and I don't want to add another build tool.

Comment: I think, [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template) should work in a similar way. But there are no documentation at all.